# go time package constants instead of digits

Tags: go

is it possible to use constants instead of digits in Format func

```
time.Unix(1392899576, 0).Format(stdLongYear +"/"+ stdZeroMonth +"/"+ stdZeroDay)
```

instead of

```
time.Unix(1392899576, 0).Format("2006/01/02")
```

Comment: Yes, why not, this variants are the same, everywhere strings in second parameter

Comment: yeah, but I wouldn't to define constants "manually", I want to use http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/format.go from this

Comment: Ah no, in this way no, they are not exported from time module

Comment: are you sure? because it looks like "good style", but do it manually - it does not look good

Comment: Yes, exported identifier must begin with an
upper-case letter

Comment: @qwertmax the constants in time/format.go are internal constants and not part of the time API. The method you're supposed to use is the method where you write an example date in the format you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant. Those constant start with a lower case letter and thus are not exported.

the only way to mimic that package is to either copy it or to re-create the constants in your own package like below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    stdLongYear  = "2006"
    stdZeroMonth = "01"
    stdZeroDay   = "02"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(1392899576, 0).Format(stdLongYear + "/" + stdZeroMonth + "/" + stdZeroDay))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/wTwMLbheCM

Comment: the question was, how to use go defined constants http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/format.go